# JSON from Play Framework could not be parsed by jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, playframework

I've used Play Framework to create a web service. I used the **renderJSON** to produce JSON format of a list of objects. and Here is the result of the JSON

```
[{"description":"Fashion shop","radius":0,"id":1},{"description":"Women Shop","radius":25,"id":2}]
```

Now, from the client I consume that web service using JQuery1.4 **$.getJSON()** and here is the jQuery code

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:9000/data/1/1/json", function(data) {
    alert('');

    $.each(data, function(i,item){
      alert('test');        
    });
});
```

I also have tried to change the code to use **$.ajax** instead and here is the code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:9000/mall/1/1/json",
    dataType:"json",    
    success:function(response){     
        alert("Details saved successfully!!!");
    },
    error:function (jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(jqXHR.status);
        alert(ajaxOptions);
        alert(thrownError);
    }    
});
```

After running the page, none of the alert above is shown, I suspect that there's a incompatible JSON syntax from the web service with JQuery's JSON. Because from what I read here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/   in JQuery1.4 if there's any syntax error the `getJSON` will fail silently.

- Is there anything wrong with my code?
- Is it because the [], that is put at the first an last of the JSON produced that it can't be parsed by jQuery JSON?

Comment: `[]` symbolized that this is an array of object.

Comment: Have you tried `jqXHR Object`, to see the error?

Comment: I'm new to JQuery AJAX. Do you mean by using the $.ajax, and what should I see the error from jqXHR, is it jqXHR.status?

Comment: On the page http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/, there is a sction on jqXHR, read it and try.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try the URL by hand ? (I mean in a browser)

The first alert('') should show up in any case, so somehow the data is not coming through, but it may not be a format error.

Try to use [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and add a error handler to see what is coming back.
Also, if you are working with the Chrome browser, try to see if your request goes to the server properly.

Comment: I tried to use $.ajax instead. In the error handler I alert all of the parameter:  alert(xmlHttpRequest.status), alert(ajaxOptions), alert(thrownError). and the 3 alerts are: '0', 'error', 'undefined'.
 
I've tried to access the url from a browser and it response with a JSON as I've posted above

Comment: In the ajax call, did you try to ask the format as text instead of json and see if the data was coming back ?

Comment: I've  tried to change the dataType:"text", and it's still error with 3 alerts: '0', 'error', '' . The third alert becomes an empty string instead of 'undefined' because I change to use JQuery1.7 instead of JQuery1.4. Wonder what went wrong..

Comment: Done. I guess there's something to do with the url, when I copy the result of running http://localhost:9000/data/1/1/json on a browser to a static file called data.json and change the url parameter of the $.ajax, it returns successfully.

Comment: thanks. what does alert(jqXHR) return ? 
Then yet again, have you use Chrome or Firebug to see if your request was going all the way to the server ?

Comment: Thanks, alert(jqXHR) returns Object. I'm sorry I don't know how to debug this request with Firebug or Chrome. I'll find it out, and report to you after it.

Comment: From what I see in Chrome (network tab of inspect elment), the request is cancelled, the type of the request is undefined and I see this error in Console of Chrome "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/mall.json. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.". But in Firebug, the result is 200 ok, with content-length is 147.